# Difference between findById({_id:historyId}) and findById(historyId) in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I was working on one of my project and came across this and it got me bit confused.
I want to understand that if both will give the same output if yes the why?

```
async getHistory( historyId: string) {
        const { historyId } = query;
        var history = await HistoryModel.findById(historyId);

        //what will happen if i do like this.

        var history = await HistoryModel.findById({_id:hisotryId})
        if (!history) {
            throw new Error(400, ` not found`, ` not found`)
        }
        return history;
    }
```

Comment: `findById(historyId)` and `findById({_id:hisotryId})` will result in exactly the same way but the second way does not make use of the shorthand benefits of just passing a single value.

Answer (score 0):

The second call to `findById` is wrong. Mongoose's `findById` takes a single ID, not an object.

The second call probably meant to use `findOne`.
In that case, `HistoryModel.findOne({ _id: historyId })` does the same thing as `HistoryModel.findById(historyId)` with the small caveat mentioned below.

You can find more information in the Docs:

> [findById] Finds a single document by its `_id` field. `findById(id)` is almost* equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`. If you want to query by a document's `_id`, use `findById()` instead of `findOne()`.

> `*` Except for how it treats `undefined`. If you use `findOne()`, you'll see that `findOne(undefined)` and `findOne({ _id: undefined })` are equivalent to `findOne({})` and return arbitrary documents. However, mongoose translates `findById(undefined)` into `findOne({ _id: null })`.

(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findById())